# Buttons in JSP Table

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have JSP page with a table:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
    <thead class="thead-light">
    <th scope="col">#</th>
    <th scope="col">Number</th>
    <th scope="col">Tariff</th>
    <th scope="col">Cost</th>
    <th scope="col">Action</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${contractsList}" var="contract" varStatus="loop">

    <thead>
        <th scope="col">${loop.index + 1}</th>
        <th>${contract.number}</th>
        <th>${contract.tariffName}</th>
        <th>TODO</th>
        <th><input type="submit" value="Block"></th>
    </thead>


    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How can I make a button in each row send POST request with data from this row? For example, I'm pressing a button in row #2 and it sends post request to some url with number of contract from this row as a request parameter. I tried adding `<form>` tag but it ruins formatting of the table and for me it's not clear how to pass contract's number as a request parameter in this case.

UPDATE: I did it this way

```
<tr onclick="showContract('${contract.contractId}')"  style="cursor: pointer;">

<script>
    function showContract(id) {
        var form = document.createElement('form');
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.method = 'post';
        form.action = '/client/show_contract';
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'hidden';
        input.name = 'contractId';
        input.value = id;
        form.appendChild(input);

        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to put your form tag inside the loop.

```
<c:forEach items="${contractsList}" var="contract" varStatus="loop"> 
<form action="..YourServlet" method="post">
<thead>
<th scope="col">${loop.index + 1}</th>
<th>${contract.number}</th> 
<th>${contract.tariffName}</th>
<th>TODO</th> 
<th><input type="submit" value="Block"></th> 
</thead> 
<input type="hidden" name="cnumber" value="${contract.number}"/>
<input type="hidden" name="ctarrif" value="${contract.tarrifName}"/>
</form>
</c:forEach>
```

Then in your servlet just get parameters like you would normally do:

```
String contractNumber = request.getParameter ("cname");
String tarrifName = request.getParameter ("ctarrif");
```